# Copying HTML formatted text from JTextPane to Notepad++

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I am working on a JtextPane and I am loading an HTML file using `textPane.setPage(url)`. It is appearing proper in HTML format, but when I select all and click on copy and paste it to Notepad++, it doesn't appear in proper html format; instead it shows content of html file in one line. I want to paste the exact html formatted text on Notepad++ as it shows on JTextPane.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Attaching the JTextPane code.

```
    textPane = New JtextPane();
    textPane.setContentType( "text/html" );
    textPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    HTMLEditorKit htmlEditor = new HTMLEditorKit();
    Document doc = htmlEditor.createDefaultDocument();
    textPane.setEditorKit( htmlEditor );
    textPane.setDocument( doc );
    textPane.setEditable( false );
    textPane.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
    textPane.getActionMap();
    textPane.setFont( EpsilonTheme.getFontA().deriveFont( 17.0F ) );
```

Comment: Notepad++ will not render HTML, AFAIK. At least not without some plugin maybe. It will just treat the the HTML markup as text. That's it. It's a (plain) text editor.

Comment: Just saw, notepad++ has an HTML-Preview Plugin. Maybe you can use that?

Comment: please show us some code..!! what have you tried?

Comment: @Fildor Before using JtextPane to render Html i was using awt.canvas.Using Canvas i haven't faced this issue. I was able to copy and paste the text in HTML formatted text on NotePad. Due to some reason i can not use awt components thats why i am using JTextPane.

Comment: Anybody have some idea about it ??

Answer (score 0):

After u past go to "languages" and choose HTML 
[image]

Comment: As I understood, I think OP is not talking about code highlighting but wants the HTML to be rendered ... but not sure ...

Comment: Thanks for Response , but i am talking about HTML rendering when we copy and paste from JTextPane, I tried using languages option before in notpad++ but its only printing html content in one line{Not working}. I want HTML formatted text to be copied so that we don't need to select language option or other stuff.